# Agregar tabla con PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Estoy usando la librería PHPExcel para generar un reporte con registros de una base de datos, investigando un poco encontré que se puede cargar una tabla previamente generada, usando la función `createReader('HTML)` y posteriormente agregandola con `loadIntoExisting`.
Pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de indicarle que la tabla comience en determinada fila y columna. Por el momento solo he podido hacer que inicie filas abajo agregando un `<br>` al crear la tabla, lo que tampoco se me hace muy limpio. Agradecería si alguien puede orientarme.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien la pregunta se requiere insertar valores a partir digamos de la segunda fila porque ya están definidas las cabeceras.

Creo que un pequeño ejemplo dará la estructura que se requiere:

```
include_once('PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

//Se configura el nombre del archivo
$fileName = 'ficheroExcelPHP';

//Se prepara un registro de arreglos que se incluriran en el fichero
$datosExcel = array(
    0 => array('Mercado','Barbara','27','F'),
    1 => array('Caceres','Andres','25','M'),
    2 => array('Bustamante','Juan','28','M'),
    3 => array('Gonzales','Eduardo','29','M'),
);

// se crea un nuevo objeto PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Se configura las propiedades del Documento
// De acuerdo a lo que se requiera
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Me")->setLastModifiedBy("Me")->setTitle("My Excel Sheet")->setSubject("My Excel Sheet")->setDescription("Excel Sheet")->setKeywords("Excel Sheet")->setCategory("Me");

// Se configura el indice en cero para que excel abra la primera hoja
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Se agrega las cabeceras 
// esto implica que $datosExcel
// va tener que empezar en la segunda fila
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Apellido')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Edad')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Sexo')
            ;

// Se colocan los arreglos previamente definidos en
// $datosExcel en las Columnas A, B, C y D empezando de la fila 2
// En primera instancia parece que se requiere de Dos Bucles(+)/ for
// pero el truco esta en usar el indice $i que indica la columna o posición
// del respectivo arreglo en $datosExcel para luego anhadirle un dos en este caso
// y asi empiece a partir de la segunda fila
for($i=0; $i<count($datosExcel); $i++){
    $ii = $i+2; // aca se le indica que empiece de la segunda fila
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$ii, $datosExcel[$i][0]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$ii, $datosExcel[$i][1]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$ii, $datosExcel[$i][2]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$ii, $datosExcel[$i][3]);

}

// Se configura el nombre del archivo
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($fileName);

// RESTO DEL CODDIGO
```

**(+)/** Sólo quería acotar que también es posible emplear los bucles `for` anidados, si por ejemplo los datos están definidos en diferentes columnas o son más de cuatro a efecto de no repetir código.

```
$columnasExcel = array('A','D','F','G','H',...) // las que se necesiten
```

Aquí se presento de esta forma para que se pueda visualizar con un `echo $i. "<br>"; echo $ii. "<br>";...` el comportamiento de los datos a insertarse en **Excel** desde **PHP**